# read all the files in a directory javascript

Tags: javascript, npm, directory, fs, readdir

I want to open a directory which containes a lot of files. I need to copy same information from every file, so I should be able to do something like this:

```
readdir('directory_name', (err, files) => {
if (err)
    console.log(err);
else {
    files.forEach(file => {
        //copy what I want from the files
    })
}
})
```

The problem is that the console gives me "readdir is not a function" and in the node_modules folder, in the fs section, there is a "README.md" file with this: "This package name is not currently in use, but was formerly occupied
by another package. To avoid malicious use, npm is hanging on to the
package name, but loosely, and we'll probably give it to you if you
want it.

You may adopt this package by contacting support@npmjs.com and
requesting the name."

I'm using Javascript on browser.

Is it possible to open the directory in another way with the same result?

I'm a beginner in JavaScript programming.

Comment: You can't read a filesystem using JavaScript in a browser. You can't use filesystem related NodeJs functions in a browser. It's not really what you're trying to achieve. Where is this directory? On the client? On a server?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The directory is on my computer. 
I was trying to use Nodejs functions in a browser using Browserify. 
So it's impossible to open a directory in my pc with javascript from the browser?

Comment: Yes, it's impossible.